# Can we Produce Messages to AWS MSK from AWS Managed Airflow DAG?

Tags: airflow, aws-msk, mwaa

Can we produce messages to AWS MSK from AWS Managed Airflow DAG?
There is a custom provider available https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-kafka/stable/index.html
But it didn't work with the `aws-mwaa-local-runner`

I tried to add the provider in the requirements file, but it's erroring out because `librdkafka/rdkafka.h: No such file or directory`